# Can you apply for UK Tier IV visa from outside your home country?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, covid-19, biometric-passports

I'm trying to apply for a UK tier IV visa to start on a PhD course starting in October. While the UKVI office is taking applications, there are no visa application centers open (or any date given to reopen) in the US to collect biometric data. So, I have two questions:

1. Can the visa office use previous biometric data for a new residence card?
2. Is it possible to apply for a Tier IV visa outside of your home country while on a visitor visa to another country?

Comment: We can only answer travel questions here. You can ask this question on our sister site, [expatriates.se].